# The log for database 'tempdb' is not available

Tags: sql-server

```
2017-07-06 05:53:02.69 spid17s     Error: 17065, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2017-07-06 05:53:02.69 spid17s     SQL Server Assertion: File: <latch.cpp>, line = 1538 Failed Assertion = '0' Attempted release of unacquired latch. This error may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the statement, use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural integrity, or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures are not corrupted.
2017-07-06 05:53:02.69 spid17s     Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     **Dump thread - spid = 17, PSS = 0x1589E7D8, EC = 0x1589E7E0
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     ***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump1824.txt
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     * *******************************************************************************
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     *
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     *   07/06/17 05:53:02 spid 17
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     *
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     * Location:      latch.cpp:1538
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     * Expression:    0
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     * SPID:          17
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     * Process ID:    4572
2017-07-06 05:53:02.70 spid17s     * Description:   Attempted release of unacquired latch
```

The above is the error log details. It seems there is some issue with tempdb corruption. The instance restart fixed the issue and sql dump creation stopped.

What seems to have resolved is that tempdb gets recreated after the restart. What are your views on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's likely a memory problem, or possible database corruption somehwere in your system. Run `CHECKDB` on all of your databases, and ensure that you do not have any hardware problems.

As for tempdb getting recreated, well yes, in a sense that is true, all objects are cleared, but the files themselves are not recreated (except in the circumstance that you manually delete the files from the OS). I Would recommend reading [this post on the zeroing out of log files in tempdb](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/does-the-tempdb-log-file-get-zero-initialized-at-startup/).

Comment: I doubt the tempdb corruption which got fixed when restarted. Thank you for your valuable answer. Will research more on this and post if I find something.